# Gradle: Configure Repository for transitive dependencies

Tags: gradle

imagine you have to go through proxy repositories for all dependency resolutions, because you are behind a proxy.

For most repositories, this can be easily configured within the `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { ... }
}
```

and

```
repositories { ... }
```

and even in `settings.gradle` the

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories { ... }
}
```

but it seems that transitive dependencies are still downloaded through jCenter.

Where can I configure the repositories for transitive dependencies?

**Update**: I still try to find the real root cause of my problem. It could be that it has to do with the way I've build my build script - the dependencies are defined in a script plugin of a sub project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why my system behaves this way, but here is a solution which works for me:

create a file called `init.gradle` in `USER_HOME/.gradle/` and add your repositiories like this:

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories { ... }
    }
    repositories { ... }
}
```